# Meaning of (052) at the end of text literal?

Tags: abap, literals

Really just a curious question.
Here are a few examples of the same concern that I have since they are being exported to the FM "REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY" for parameter "it_fieldcat".

```
ls_fieldcat-seltext_l     = 'Material number'(052).
ls_fieldcat-seltext_m     = 'Material'(053).
ls_fieldcat-seltext_s     = 'Mat.'(054).
```

I tried removing the numbers on the right and executed the program but I didn't see any differences and I also tried to see what happens inside debug mode but it only fills the field with the string value, am I missing something or is there something that I wasn't able to notice?

I've been tasked to create a copy of a program which originally joins multiple tables and filters them according to the Parameters from the SELECTION-SCREEN and then shows the results in an ALV Grid Report, but for the use case of the copy it should instead populate a table in ECC that we will then be replicating to BW side. I have successfully copied and modified it accordingly but I can't seem to understand what the numbers beside the strings are doing.

Can someone please explain what their use is, would be very grateful to see a few examples.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number in the brackets is a [text symbol](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abentext_symbols.htm#:%7E:text=A%20text%20symbol%20is%20a,the%20text%20elements%20by%20mlen.) defined as a part of the text elements of the program. Using the syntax 'Literal'(idf) replaces these literals in the program if the symbol is in the currently loaded text pool.

Comment: To elaborate on the purpose of this: It makes the string literal translatable. When you log into the system in a different language and run the program, and the text-pool of the program has another string for that language for symbol 052, then "Material number" will be replaced by the localized string.